# Toggle all button text when any button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three panels, they need to **not** operate individually, i.e. if you click on any of the hide details p tags (buttons) all panel details will hide. I need the same behaviour for the button text change, but currently its only happening on an individual basis instead of as a group.

HTML

```
    <div class="col-sm compare-card">
    <div class="compare-card-header">
        <h4 style="display:inline-block">Title</h4>
        <a href="#" class="tooltip-trigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="tooltip text" style="" class="black-tooltip"><img src="images/tooltip.svg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-balance">
        <p class="benefit-title">title</p>
        <p class="f-14">subtitle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-attributes">
        text here
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-footer">
        <p class="hide-show-attributes"><span id="toggleShow">Hide Details</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm compare-card">
    <div class="compare-card-header">
        <h4 style="display:inline-block">Title</h4>
        <a href="#" class="tooltip-trigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="tooltip text" style="" class="black-tooltip"><img src="images/tooltip.svg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-balance">
        <p class="benefit-title">title</p>
        <p class="f-14">subtitle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-attributes">
        text here
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-footer">
        <p class="hide-show-attributes"><span id="toggleShow">Hide Details</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm compare-card">
    <div class="compare-card-header">
        <h4 style="display:inline-block">Title</h4>
        <a href="#" class="tooltip-trigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="tooltip text" style="" class="black-tooltip"><img src="images/tooltip.svg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-balance">
        <p class="benefit-title">title</p>
        <p class="f-14">subtitle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-attributes">
        text here
    </div>
    <div class="compare-card-footer">
        <p class="hide-show-attributes"><span id="toggleShow">Hide Details</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    //COMPARISON CARD SCRIPT---------------
//This wll show and hide the card attributes section inside the card
jQuery('.hide-show-attributes').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.compare-card-attributes').toggleClass('clicked-hide');
 });

//This will toggle the text on the show hide p tag button messaging
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.compare-card-footer').find(".hide-show-attributes").click(function(){;
        if($(this).find("span#toggleShow").text()=="Hide Details"){
            $(this).find("span#toggleShow").text("Show Details");
        }
        else{
            $(this).find("span#toggleShow").text("Hide Details");
        }
    });
});
//END COMPARISON CARD SCRIPT---------------
```

CSS

```
.clicked-hide {
display: none;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `toggleShow` is an id. You cannot have two elements with the same id in HTML. Turn them into classes and it should work.

```
<span class="toggleShow">Hide Details</span>
```

And

```
if($(this).find("span.toggleShow").first().text()=="Hide Details"){
    $("span.toggleShow").text("Show Details");
}
else {
    $("span.toggleShow").text("Hide Details");
}
```

You cannot use `$(this)` as it points to the `.hide-show-attributes` element.

Comment: No problem. :-)